# Which is higher — "hyper-", "ultra-" or "super-"?

Tags: meaning, prefixes, comparisons

According to OED,

- [*hyper-*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/90273?rskey=zGjcrt&result=4&isAdvanced=false#eid):

  > over, beyond, over much, above measure
- [*ultra-*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/208684?rskey=8zEBz2&result=3&isAdvanced=false#eid):

  > beyond
- [*super-*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194186?rskey=LmVyFi&result=20&isAdvanced=false#eid):

  > over, above, higher than

They all have the meaning "higher than", but what is the order of them? That is, which one is the highest? Which one is modest higher? And which one is middle higher?

**Update:** Thank you all.

I have searched by myself and spotted that, according to [Taxonomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank), *hyperfamily* is larger than *superfamily*. Moreover, as Kris, Mitch and Robusto pointed out, *hyper* is higher than *super* in many other usage such as hypersonic/supersonic and hypermarket/supermarket. In addition *super* is higher than *ultra* in Audiology. So it seems

> *ultra* < *super* < *hyper*

in common usage. On the other hand, in [taxonomic ranks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxonomic_rank) of biological classification, the rank *hypoorder* is larger than *suborder*, which is larger than *infraorder*. So a conclusion seems can be made as *infra* < *sub* < *hypo*.

Overall, does it seem the order is

> *infra* < *sub* < *hypo* < *ultra* < *super* < *hyper*

in most usages?

Comment: In American English, 'ultra-' feels more extreme than 'super-' (by association with it's usage in gasoline varieties), and 'hyper-' is just of another kind altogether and so is not comparable (i.e. there is 'hyperactive' but no 'superactive', there is 'supermarket' but no 'hypermarket').

Comment: @Mitch [Hypermarkets do exist](http://www.carrefour.com/cdc/group/our-business/our-stores/our-stores-folder/hypermarket.html). Haven't seen an ultramarket yet though.

Comment: You really can never have a definitive ordering for things like this; it's just a set of words that different speakers will at different times perceive differently. It isn't like you're inflecting things into comparative and superlative degrees. I don't think it is possible to have a definitive ordering that all speakers agree on.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: The French call a supermarket 'hypermarche'. That is a loan translation into English for French brand supermarkets that have sites in English speaking countries. I don't think any are yet in the US, so there is no 'hypermarket' there (as I specified, in American English).

Comment: @Mitch Actually, that isn't quite right.  The word you were looking for is **actually** spelled [***hypermarché***](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypermarché).  What you wrote would be verb in the third person of the present indicative, as in the ironic exchange *Ça marche?  Oui, ça marche un peu, mais ça n'hypermarche pas*. :)

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for pointing that out. My keyboard doesn't have accents. It was intended to be with the accent.

Comment: Given your edits and extra questions, I'd say that primarily it's mostly vague, but if forced to order them, it would be super < hyper < ultra. and no order possible on sub, infra, hypo (the latter two are so rarely used as to have little association with any particular strength).

Comment: I did an analysis of unixes /usr/shar/dict/words wordlist and found 22 triples (all three  of super, hyper, and ultra used) and 241 pairs. The most interesting is the root 'conservative', which combines chaotically: hyperconservatism, ultraconservatism, hyperconservative, superconservative, ultraconservative, hyperconservatively, superconservatively, hyperconservativeness, superconservativeness

Comment: The French definitely have a concept of "supermarché" and "hypermarché", of which the latter is bigger than the former. http://quelledifference.info/quelle-difference-entre-un-supermarche-et-un-hypermarche/

Comment: "Hyper" is always greater than "super", and what we just had in Minneapolis, on Feb 14 2018, was "HyperBowlLII", alas, never to return.

Comment: hypo is not the same as hyper, quite the opposite, see for example hyperthermia and hypothermia, in that context I think it would be safe to say hyper > hypo

Answer (score 25, accepted):

These are not English words, but Greek (*hyper*) and Latin (*super, ultra*) prepositions.

*Hyper* and *super* mean exactly the same thing, 'above' -- they're cognates, in fact; Greek initial S went to H, and Y was the Greek letter corresponding to Latin V (or U). Greek is of course more prestigious than Latin, but it's not bigger.

*Ultra*, on the other hand, means 'beyond', as in *ultraviolet* or *ultra vires* 'beyond (the powers of) men'.

So I guess *ultra* would be the ultimate (same root, btw), at least for English speakers who've studied Latin and Greek.

All of them.

Comment: They are of Greek origin, but I think they're well enough assimilated that we can call them English words at this point.

Comment: If this were true, "superhypersensitive" would mean the same as *"hypersupersensitive".

Comment: And to most people, they would mean the same thing, absent a convention.

Answer (score 11):

John Lawler is right that they mean mostly the same thing. But in terms of actual usage, *hyper-* is often used when something more than *super-* is needed. For example, an aircraft that flies faster than the speed of sound is called *supersonic*. But there arose a need to distinguish between mere *supersonic* speed and something far beyond that. So *hypersonic* was next in line. From Wikipedia's article on [hypersonic speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypersonic_speed):

> In aerodynamics, a hypersonic speed is one that is highly supersonic (even though the origin of the words is the same—"super" is just the Latin version of the Greek "hyper"). Since the 1970s, the term has generally been assumed to refer to speeds of Mach 5 and above.

This pattern repeats often in engineering and scientific terminology.

*Hyper-* is also used when *super-*, due to its extreme overuse, doesn't feel technical or academic enough. Saying that someone exhibits "super-sensitivity" may mean the same thing as exhibiting "hyper-sensitivity," but the latter term is used by psychologists. (Cf. "hyper-vigilance" and other psych terms).

Additionally, where a word using *super-* already has a distinct and different meaning, *hyper-* is the go-to substitute. *Supercritical* already has an established meaning in science, so *hypercritical* is used to describe someone who is scolding and sarcastic all the time.

I personally would reserve *ultra-* as the ultimate superlative (if you will allow the pun).

Comment: Is *Hyperman* stronger than *Superman*? Or did he just drink more coffee?

Comment: The ultimate superlative lol

Comment: Does the copyright for Superman® cover _Hyperman_ too? Or can we resuscitate the Big Red Cheese?

Comment: @JohnLawler: That's the rumor, but I think it's just a lot of hype.

Answer (score 4):

The terms used for size, especially in promotional materials do not follow strict logical or grammatical rules. While there may be subtle arguments as to which term truly conveys the most of something or a logical order, these are largely ignored in practice.

Consider the sizes of olives. This is part the sequence for International grading by size:

> - Superior
> - Large
> - Extra Large
> - Jumbo
> - Extra Jumbo
> - Giants
> - Colossal
> - Super Colossal
> - Mammoth
> - Super Mammoth

This is part of the list for American grading

> - Large
> - Extra Large
> - Mammoth
> - Giant
> - Jumbo
> - Colossal
> - Super Colossal

Notice that in the US, Colossal is larger than Mammoth, but the orders are reversed in International standards. In no case is the actual size of olives in one system equivalent in size in the other. Note that these are accepted standards recognized by governments, not just commercial *hype*.

Sometimes *Super* is bigger/faster/brighter/tighter than *Ultra*. Sometimes it's not.

Comment: What in the world ever happened to olives of small, medium, and regular size?

Comment: @tchrist For a change, we Americans actually still use some real terms for the smaller sizes - *sub-petite, petite, midget, small (but also called select or standard), medium*. The International standard uses *bullets, fine, brilliant and superior*. Now lets check Starbucks where the smallest size is called *tall*.

Comment: I see.  [Here](http://www.sizes.com/food/olives.htm) it gives the Californian rankings as Sub-petite, Petite, Small, Medium, Large, Extra Large, Jumbo, Colossal, and Super Colossal, and notes that Europe uses the same words differently.

Comment: @tchrist That is the source my lists came from. Note that even with in the US there are different labels.

Comment: @bib the smallest size at Starbucks is *short* (8oz).

Comment: @cornbreadninja Either that size is new or it hasn't made it to my neighborhood. I resist and just ask for *medium* instead of *venti* (whatever that means - 20 oz.? a sub-oceanic volcanic plume?)

Comment: @bib it isn't new.  Some of the baristas know it as 'kid's hot chocolate' size, and some just don't know about it at all.  The one at the airport doesn't have it.  I like a double latte at that size.  http://www.slate.com/articles/arts/everyday_economics/2006/01/starbucks_economics.html

Comment: Mammoth olives sounds absolutely bizarre. Would a tiny little woolly mammoth also be called an olive mammoth, I wonder..?

Answer (score 3):

Could be general reference. The prefixes have definite meanings in Aerodynamics, Audiology and other fields. However, note that the definitions may not apply across domains -- are not hard and fast in general English, and certainly not in non-technical prose.

[Electromagnetic Spectrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_spectrum) (Wikipedia)

> EHF= Extremely high frequency
>   SHF= Super high frequency
>   UHF= Ultra high frequency

[super, hyper and ultra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aReference_desk/Archives/Language/2010_February_2#super.2C_hyper_and_ultra)
"in some cases ... ultra was named first, and then they found higher frequencies, so super was attached after the ultra. --Ludwigs2" :)

*Supersonic* and *hypersonic* in Aerodynamics occur in that order. *Supersonic* is speed above the speed of sound; *hypersonic* five times or more than the speed of sound.

*Ultrasonic* is defined as being **beyond** human audio range (threshold of hearing), not really related to the other two terms.

Comment: Right, "ultrasonic" refers to high frequency while "supersonic" and "hypersonic" refer to high linear speed.

Comment: And megasonic is even higher frequency than ultrasonic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no fixed ordering of the three. If you have a need to specify levels of "superness" and you want to use these words, you could put them in any order you like and there would be no objective grounds to say you were wrong.

I'm reminded of the time I was buying laundry detergent and I found that one brand came in three sizes: "large", "family size", and "economy size". Which of those do you suppose was the biggest? The labels were useless. (BTW, "large" was actually the smallest size.)

Comment: "large" = more than enough for ordinary use. "family size" = enough for a whole family of people. "economy size" = enough to qualify for a quantity discount.

Answer (score 1):

I like to follow the Pokemon way of doing thing. If it is great enough for Pokemon, most of the time it is also for my case:

The [Potion scale](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Potion): Normal < Super < Hyper < Max

The [Poké Ball scale](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pok%C3%A9_Ball): Normal < Great < Ultra < Master

As far as I know Pokemon doesnt mix super/hyper with ultra, but as others said I would use Super < Hyper < Ultra.

Answer (score -1):

For figurative, stylistic use, any order is acceptable.  Nevertheless, for precise accuracy, I agree with the commentary above regarding the Greek and Latin roots -- and the one who wrote about speeds.  They express the root mwanings and a usage example.

Super and Hyper are more-of (yet still of the same substance)  while Ultra is outside or beyond such.

Another example, in reading this, one could be critical or complementary, or super critical-or-complementary (if they're in the mood for such). One could be hyper, but such would be excessive.  If one was ultra, they would pass out of the realm of critique and into the realm of flirty or insulting.  `