# Using superlatives as prefixes, order of significance

Tags: prefixes, superlative-degree

This is kind of an opinion-leaning question.

I'm naming a set of items based on their order of significance. Their names will be prefixed with the following superlatives: *super, ultra, mega, hyper, giga, epic,* and more (in fact, if you have any more that would sound good as a prefix please feel free to list them).

In what order should these be?

---

This is not the same question at all: [Which is higher — "hyper-", "ultra-" or "super-"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87330/which-is-higher-hyper-ultra-or-super) I even clearly stated in a comment that it was not:

> The answers there aren't what I'm looking for. The Greek and Latin
>   roots are obvious (for anyone who has studied them, as I), but **not
>   exactly useful here**. In this case **they all have the same
>   meaning**.

I even stated I was looking for opinions. I also have words that were never addressed in that question.

Comment: It's an entirely opinion-based question and probably isn't a good fit for this site. If you wanted guidance on how to use superlatives an what they mean, you might be able to reword your question to be more suitable, if that would help you.

Comment: And yet there are opinion based questions all over this site. There is even an 'opinion' tag already.

Comment: I like super-duper.  You should look at the answers to the question I mentioned as a possible duplicate.  Much of what you ask is answered there.  However, Giga is larger than mega: A gigabuck is one billion dollars (i.e., a thousand million); a megabuck is one million dollars.

Comment: The answers there aren't what I'm looking for. The Greek and Latin roots are obvious (for anyone who has studied them, as I), but not exactly useful here. In this case they all have the same meaning.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of that question. It's pretty dumb how people can just assume my answers are there when they are NOT. I clearly stated how it was different from that question. None of the answers in that question address my question at all.

Comment: @CoreyIles If it's any consolation, even if we were to remove the closure for duplicate, the question would be immediately re-closed as "primarily opinion based", because you've said explicitly you are looking for opinions. Take what you can, if anything, from that other question, and let it go. If you want to poll opinion, try Yahoo! Answers or even Twitter.

Comment: Sorry that I closed this as duplicate, sometimes I rush things. It is clear to me now. This should be closed, instead, as **primarily opinion based**. And what @DanBron said.

Comment: It's not PRIMARILY opinion based. And even if it was, why is there an "opinion" tag? This should remain open, it's a completely valid question here.

Comment: All naming questions are off topic. http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @CoreyIles Anyone can create tags, simply by typing whatever they like, or whatever pops into their heads, in the tags field when they post a question. Unless a tag is abused often enough for the rest of us to notice, it can stick around. The [tag:opinion] tag is a mistake, created by a novice user, and we will remove it: thank you for bringing it to our attention. Returning to your question here, it's no use word-lawyering, it won't get you anywhere. Subjective questions are off-topic here and broadly across the SE network. IOW: no, it is *not* a valid question here. You are incorrect.